# Why does a chained filter() call re-trigger the function it is made from?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, filter

I'm used to doing something like this:

```
$(some_elements)
   .filter(function() { return $(this).jqmData("locked") !== true; })
       .jqmData('locked', true )
       .each( function(){
         // stuff
       });
```

so my filter call picks all "unlocked" elements, runs a function on them and locks them up, so they are excluded the next time.

Right now I'm trying to use this filter inside a widget factory function:

```
...
_create: function() {
    var self = this;
    self.refresh( true );
},

refresh: function ( create ) {
...
    $filter
        .submit( function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            search.blur();
        })
        .bind( "submit", function() {
            return false;
        })
        .filter(function() { return this.getAttribute( "data-override" ) !== false; })
            .find( "input" )
                .bind( "keyup change input", self.filter( e, kids ) )
                .end()
            .end()
        .prepend( o.target || $( container ) );
},
...
```

When I'm using it here, the call to the `filter()` re-triggers my `_create` function and I have no idea why. If I leave away the filter, all works ok, so it must be in my filtering call.

**Question**:
What am I doing wrong in the filter() function?

**EDIT:**
So this is not chained but works:

```
 $filter
    .submit( function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        search.blur();
    })
    .prependTo( $( o.target ) || $( el ) );

 if ( $(this).jqmData("override") === false ) {
    $filter
        .find( "input" )
        .bind( "keyup change input", function() {
            self.filter( e, kids );
        });
 }
```

while this does not (refires `_create`):

```
$filter
    .submit( function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        search.blur();
    })
    .filter( function() {
        console.log($(this).data("override"))
        return $(this).data("override");
    })
    .find("input")
        .bind( "keyup change input", function() {
            self.filter( e, kids );
    })
    .end()
    .end()
    .prependTo( $( o.target ) || $( el ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

these two event handlers are exactly the same:

```
.submit( function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        search.blur();
    })
    .bind( "submit", function() {
        return false;
    })
```

This one executes the function immediately and returns the result:

```
.bind( "keyup change input", self.filter( e, kids ) )
```

and should probably be:

```
    .bind( "keyup change input", function() {
       self.filter( e, kids );
    })
    .end() ....
```

and you'd end up with:

```
$filter.on('submit',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    search.blur();
}).filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("override");
}).find("input").on('keyup change input', function() {
    self.filter(e, kids);
}).end().end().prepend(o.target || $(container);
```

or

```
$filter.prependTo(o.target || $(container)
       .on('submit',function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           search.blur();
     }).filter(function() {
           return $(this).data("override");
     }).find("input")
       .on('keyup change input', function() {
           self.filter(e, kids);
 });
```

Comment: nope. It still re-triggers my widget _create function. Give me a minute, I post what's not working and what's working.

Comment: Did you try removing one of the `end()` statements, as there looks to be one too many ?

Comment: Nope, there should be two, did'nt notice the find().

Comment: Did you try without the OR statement in the prependTo function ?

Comment: yes. That's not it. The problem is the `.filter()` call. If I leave that away everything works.